# What datatype should be used in VB.NET to handle a precision of like a 100 decimal numbers or more? Double seems to display only about 17

Tags: .net, vb.net, types

What datatype should be used in VB.NET to handle a precision of like a 100 decimal numbers or more? Double seems to display only about 17.

Comment: [VB.NET data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx)

Comment: System.Numerics.BigInteger, after multiplying your numbers by a googol.  No BigDecimal type in .NET but plenty around, use google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx) can display up to 28 places to the right of the decimal according to the documentation.

There is no built in type that can handle 100. But you could potentially build your own type to handle your requirements.